# Why is boost::python::make_tuple throwing boost::python::error_already_set exception?

Tags: python, c++, boost

I am working on a Boost Python library and I trying to get both a C++ and Python client side unit test working against it.

My problem is that **boost::python::make_tuple** will throw **No to_python (by-value) converter found for C++ type: std::vector<int, std::allocator >** if my client is C++.

Here is my code:

```
using IntVec = std::vector< int >;

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(track_test_cplusplus) {

    boost::python::class_<std::vector<int  > > ("IntVec")
        .def(vector_indexing_suite<std::vector<int> > ());

}        

Test::test {

    Py_Initialize();
    boost::python::numpy::initialize();
    PyImport_ImportModule("track_test_cplusplus");

    //std::vector<int> foo {1, 2, 3, 4};
    //std::vector<int> bar {5, 6, 7, 8};
    IntVec foo {1, 2, 3, 4};
    IntVec bar {5, 6, 7, 8};
    try {
       auto foobar = boost::python::make_tuple (foo, bar);
       //auto foobar = boost::python::make_tuple ( boost::ref(foo), boost::ref(bar)); 
    } catch (...) {
       std::cout << boost::current_exception_diagnostic_information() << std::endl;
       PyErr_Print();
       return;
    }

    std::vector<int> fromtuple = boost::python::extract<std::vector<int>>(foobar[0]);
    std::cout << "Extracting from tuple...\n";
    for (auto i : fromtuple) {
        std::cout << " " << i;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
```

When this is called from a Python script, it works as expected.  ( It prints "1 2 3 4" )

When I call this code from a C++ client (defined on the stack), I get the exception.

```
Dynamic exception type: boost::python::error_already_set
TypeError: No to_python (by-value) converter found for C++ type: std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >
```

Note that the foobar variable never gets passed back to Python - it just gets instantiated and thrown away so I don't think I am looking an an Python/C++ Module.cpp issue.

I feel I must be missing some sort if initialization process that happens when the call comes over via Python but the documentation is a little thin.

I have tried adding the converted for the vector in the track_test_cplusplus module but clearly, I am not doing it correctly.

Any ideas why this method throws the exception?

Thanks,
Natasha